# Why "in der dritten" but not "in der dritte"?

Tags: dative

> Die Cafeteria ist in der dritte**n** Etage.

*Etage* is a feminine noun, *in* is dative. *Der Dritte* is the third (masculine noun).

Why is it **dritten** here?

Comment: ok, I think the reason for "dritten" is because it is dative and that is all https://blogs.transparent.com/german/german-ordinal-numbers-in-us-choosing-the-proper-gender-grammatical-case-and-number-pt-i/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase *der Dritt**e*** (or *der dritt**e** Stock*) has no *-n* because it is **nominative** singular. *Im dritt**en** Stock/Stockwerk* or *in der dritt**en** Etage* have *-en* because they are **dative** singular.

> *masculine*:
> Das ist d**er** dritt**e** Stock. (*nominative*)
> *vs.*
> Wir suchen d**en** dritt**en** Stock. (*accusative*)
> Wir sind i**m** dritt**en** Stock. (*dative*)
> die Bewohner d**es** dritt**en** Stock**s** (*genitive*)
>
> *neuter*:
> Das ist da**s** dritt**e** Stockwerk. (*nominative*)
> Wir suchen da**s** dritt**e** Stockwerk. (*accusative*)
> *vs.*
> Wir sind i**m** dritt**en** Stockwerk. (*dative*)
> die Bewohner d**es** dritt**en** Stockwerk**s**. (*genitive*)
>
> *feminine*:
> Das ist di**e** dritt**e** Etage. (*nominative*)
> Wir suchen di**e** dritt**e** Etage. (*accusative*)
> *vs.*
> Wir sind in d**er** dritt**en** Etage. (*dative*)
> die Bewohner d**er** dritt**en** Etage. (*genitive*)

Weak adjectives, i.e. those following an inflected article such as *der, den, im, die, der*, have *-e* in the nominative singular and *-en* in forms distinct from the nominative singular. Dative and genitive are always distinct from the nominative.

Note that in the masculine singular, nominative *der* and accusative *den* are distinct and therefore the adjective has *-en* in the accusative: *den dritt**en** Stock*. The dative and genitive also have *-en*.

In the neuter and feminine singular, nominative and accusative are identical and the adjective takes *-e* in both cases: *das erst**e** Stockwerk*, *die erst**e** Etage*. Only the dative and genitive have *-en*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your examples, I know that, in dative case, all weak adjectives (e.g: ordinal numbers) for all genders should +en. That is a rule which I couldn't figure out before.

Answer (score 5):

It answers the question "Wo ist die Cafeteria?" which takes the Dativ case.

https://www.das-akademie.de/en/akkusativ-and-dativ-wo-and-wohin/

Nominativ: **Die dritte Etage** ist die höchste Etage im Haus.
Genitiv: Die Beschilderung **der dritten Etage** fehlt.
Dativ: "Die Cafeteria ist in **der dritten Etage**.
Akkusativ: "Ich gehe jetzt in **die dritte Etage**.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand why dritte in dative is dritten? Is there any reason for it?

Comment: It's the **adjective declension** after the definite article. The rules for that seem somewhat arbitrary but after a while you find they are mostly about avoiding tongue-twisters.

Comment: @BằngRikimaru Declension generally has no "reason". To see why declension tables cannot be predicted from any underlying principle, just consider that German declension is slowly deteriorating from "many different endings" (Old High German) to "almost nothing" (now) and that the language has remained active and vibrant throughout it all.

Answer (score 1):

The question *wo?* requires the dative case. *Der Etage* is the Dative case of "die Etage":

> die Etage (Nominative)
>   der Etage (Genitive)
>   der Etage (Dative)
>   die Etage (Accusative)

Comment: But I still don't understand why it is "dritten" but not "dritte".

Comment: It's the adjective's declension: *die dritte Etage, der dritten Etage, der dritten Etage, die dritte Etage*. The masculine declension would be *der dritte Mann, des dritten Mannes, dem dritten Mann, den dritten Mann*, the neuter declension *das dritte Kind, des dritten Kindes, dem dritten Kind, das dritte Kind*.